# How to do a timing job on an engine that only has timing gears

Tags: timing, valve-timing, cam-timing, timing-set

I am rebuilding an engine and i need to fix the timing. The engine doesn't have a chain or belt, just a gear on the crankshaft and another one on the camshaft.

The camshaft gear has a mark but the crankshaft one doesn't. The only thing the manual specifies is when should each valve open/close.
How am i supposed to do this?

[image]

Comment: Generally there is an index mark on the gears that indicates their position when the crankshaft is at 0 degrees TDC on cylinder #1.  Perhaps if you provided some details like make, model, year, and engine model more details could be provided.

Comment: @jwh20 It is a Ducati Marine DM184HD single cylinder diesel engine.

Comment: Not exactly a mainstream engine.  You might ask around at a shop that services these.  I'm sure it's not complicated but it is critical to get it right.

Comment: There is no "shop that services these"to ask. Shouldn't i be able to find which of the 27 "teeth"  on the crankshaft gear is correct by checking which valve is open when or something?

Comment: @HandyHowie of what part exactly?

Comment: The front of the engine where the timing gears are.

Comment: @HandyHowie https://ibb.co/tm3G7FL

Comment: Can you do of for the full front of the engine?

Comment: @HandyHowie I could do that but you won't be able to see the crankshaft.

Comment: You could try contacting this guy - https://www.facebook.com/122002191187468/photos/does-anyone-else-have-a-ducati-diesel-in-their-flyer-after-9-years-i-was-finally/122008387853515/

Comment: @HandyHowie I have already tried with no success

Comment: Why did i get downvoted? I would really like to know in order to improve my questions in the future

Comment: the mark is visible on the right side of the small gear at the 3 o clock possition on your picture.

Comment: @trond hansen As i said, i know about this mark but i did not know where to align it. In my answer, i state that i found out that mark should be aligned to another mark on the crankcase while the crankshaft is at TDC. Anyway, thanks for the statement
.

Comment: as i mentioned the mark is visible on both gears in your picture,top little gear mark is visible on the tooth at 3 o clock position and the mark on the big gear is on the 1 o clock possition in the groove between the teeth,when the mark in the groove matches the mark on the tooth it is correct if the piston is at tdc.

Comment: @trond hansen i have tried that but apparently the mark was just a scratch on the crankshaft.

Comment: if you are unable or unwilling to understand this you should get somebody else to do the job for you,several of the helpful people here on our site have given you their time and advice and at this point there is not a lot more i can do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to get number 1 piston at TDC.

Once you have done that then you can engage the camshaft gear with the crank gear using that mark and looking at the camshaft so that you have it in the correct position or at least close to ie where both valves are closed.

Sometimes you need to turn the camshaft so that as the gear teeth engage the cam gets rotated to the final correct position. This is the case with helical teeth.

Comment: What do you mean with "Using that mark"?

Comment: @Hristos your words: “the camshaft gear has a mark…”

Comment: Tried searching marine/ boat engine sites using your Ducati model that can answer questions like yours? You're asking a boat engine question on an automotive site. My brief random reading of marine engines covers many old engines discontinued but still in service with forums addressing similar questions. Answers are usually from experienced boaters and marine mechanics sharing free info.

Comment: @F Dryer i am asking a general timing question on a motor vehicle site. The fact that this engine was used on a boat makes no diffirence...

Comment: @FDryer - Yes, this question is on-topic, though is a little weak on specifics.  If you have questions, please see [The Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the on-topic section which states, "*... internal combustion engines, **even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories.***"

Comment: Decades ago, before the internet, the yellow pages was my source for where to go. My father bought a Johnson 10hp outboard.  We did very little fishing, knew no one about outboard engines. In my teens I wrote to Johnson and bought a service manual. Fast forward, I  decided to rebuild a 40 yr old Sears 1.5 ton floor jack. Internet sources provided YouTube videos, links to others knowledgeable about hydraulic jack repairs and parts. I think marine forums of knowledgeable people can help. Good luck retiming this diesel engine.

Answer (score -1):

On my engine, there was a mark on the camshaft gear and an arrow on the crankcase/engine shell. I had to align these while the crankshaft was at TDC.
I also found out that the best way to do what i initially asked for is to get the crankshaft to TDC and the camshaft in the midpoint of the valve overlap.

Comment: Reads just like my answer that I gave you yesterday.

Comment: @Solar Mike You said something that was a bit unclear so if you meant that i'm sorry but what i understood was quite different than what i said

Comment: Well if you can’t understand what you said then there is little hope.