# How to set valve timing on an engine

Tags: timing, valve-timing, cam-timing

I need to redo the timing on an engine i am rebuilding. There are no timing marks and the only thing i know is when should each valve open/close. The engine is a single cylinder diesel engine. It is not assembled at all as timing must be set while closing the crankcase. I printed a degree wheel as i thought it may be useful but i don't know how to set the timing. I have failed to find instructions online.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What engine are you trying to do this on? Year/Make/Model/Displacement would be VERY handy to try and help you. Every engine model is different, so instructions will vary.

Comment: @PAULSTER2 It is a Ducati Marine DM184HD but i suspect you won't be able to find anything...

Comment: How is this question different from this one you asked before?  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/85073/how-to-do-a-timing-job-that-only-has-timing-gears

Comment: @jwh20 it was supposed to be better, more general/clear etc